# discord bot shows no activity

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

having some trouble with my discord bot's activity. No matter what im doing, the bot does not set a activity with the current gwei, not even a wrong one.
The output im receiving in the terminal matches with the current gwei

i hope some one can help me
thanks in advance

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require('@alch/alchemy-web3');

const client = new Client({
  intents: Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGES | Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS
});

const API_URL = 'https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/API-key';
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL);

const updateBotActivity = async () => {
  try {
    const gwei = await web3.eth.getGasPrice() / 10 ** 9; // Convert to GWEI
    if (gwei > 0) {
      client.user.setActivity(`${gwei.toFixed(2)} GWEI`, { type: 'WATCHING' });
      console.log(`${gwei.toFixed(2)} GWEI`);
    } else {
      console.log('GWEI value is not valid');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  updateBotActivity(); // Initial update
  setInterval(updateBotActivity, 300000); // 5-minute interval
});
```

im trying to create a discord bot which is showing me the current gas price with in the activity feed of the bot

Comment: What is `Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGES`? Where did you find it? And where do you call `updateBotActivity`?

Comment: edited the post. im sorry.

guild_message should be there for a response from a bot when im writing to him